# Prerequisites to develop iphone native application

Tags: iphone

My company is planning to develop iphone-native-applications.

I'm good with Linux.

The questions are:

Do we need a MAC machine to develop iphone-app?

Can a normal development-framework like NETBEANS / ECLIPSE suffice?

What are the other pre-requisites that i might need?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Plz, pardon with me being totally naive with this IPHONE :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need a Mac, and you need to use Xcode. (It is remotely possible and difficult to do other things, but that's really the way to go.)

It's "Mac" and "iPhone", please get that right while you still can. :)

Being good with Linux is good, as Mac OS X is one of the *nices. You'll feel mostly at home in the command line.

You may want to try a little Objective-C/Cocoa programming on the Mac first before moving to iPhone, or at least read about the syntax before you start doing real development with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mac which is intel based. Install Xcode from CD which comes as OS CD with the machine. 
There is no windows based compiler or IDE released by Apple.
OS version in this mac should be 10.5 and above. i-phone SDK can be freely downloaded.
i-phone development licence is available as individual by paying $99 for one year.
Company can get for $299. $99 based licence when you build the app, has to be released to store of apple for anyone to use. That is possible only when apple approves it..
All tools related info is at http://developer.apple.com/iphone